# How to animate sperm? - Android

Tags: android, animation, andengine

I would like to know how can I animate a sperm, Like in [This](http://footage.shutterstock.com/video.html?id=505819) link.

I need to combine this animate so the animated sperm go from the left side of the screen to the right side.

I know how to implement the movement, I just want to know how can I create the animated sperm, so I can combine him on me **Android App**(I know that flash animation doesn't work on android).

Am I need to work with another program than Eclipse? or I can implement the sperm animation in the code(With Andengine or other library)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can javascript be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1136236

Take a look..

Its made using **D3js**.. if you are willing to use javascript.
It pretty slick!

Comment: I like it, This is in JavaScript?

Comment: And eclipse supports javascript too.. so you don't have to switch.

Comment: Just one more question, From this example can i make some of the java script parameters as input for the android project? (Like the number of sperms/ speed etc..)

Comment: Am in the process of studyng d3.js... using this guy's tutorial.
http://www.youtube.com/user/d3Vienno

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple sinusoid. You can implement it with any technology and IDE.